# How to integrate a Expo React app with 'Google Play Games Services' like leaderboards and achievements?

Tags: react-native, expo, google-play-services

I would like to create a game using react native, but I can't find methods to integrate it with google play services.

Comment: did you find anything on it?

Comment: I searched a lot but found nothing :(

Comment: Not really at the end i created my own leader-board with realtime firebase db
and i didnt really need google play games services for anything other then that

Comment: Did you find anything ?

Comment: This isn't quite what you're looking for but has some overview of the basic integration process.
https://medium.com/swlh/from-expo-init-to-google-play-store-184c772d0ae I'm still looking. The last time I looked it felt like `expo eject` and doing a native app integration was the only way to go. Hoping this has changed by now.